# Which text editor to make tables scripts human readable

Tags: tables, editors

Suppose I want to edit a table

```
moon & 456456456423423534 &  2342523
sun  &             234324 &     3453
```

You see I have to enter a lot of spaces manually to align stuff. It is ok for a small table but for a large table this is inefficient.

I wonder there there is an editor that I can easily write tables in human readable script. I am familiar with vim and Ultraedit though I don't know which functionality specifically I should use. Perhaps there are software better than vim and Ultraedit for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, let me be specific. I understand how to do it in vim. But suppose my work place doesn't have vim , but only ultraedit. 
Is there a way to do this in using Ultraedit?

Comment: No vim on the workstation? Change the employer!

Comment: New question, how to do this in Kile?

Answer (score 24):

I am very happy with vim and the `tabular` plugin. To align the table, place the cursor anywhere inside the (nonaligned) table and type `:Tabularize /&`. The result is a nicely aligned table.

Before:

```
moon&456456456423423534&2342523
sun&234324&3453
```

Then a `:Tabularize /&`, after:

```
moon & 456456456423423534 & 2342523
sun  & 234324             & 3453
```

If you need this often, you can assign a custom shortcut for this.

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds. `:)` Nice plugin. There's a [video tutorial](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/) on how to use it. `:)`

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me how to assign a this function as 'control-E' in vim. I forgot the syntax of keyboard shortcut in vimrc

Comment: @ZwingliTannenbaum You can assign a mapping in command mode with `:nmap <Leader>at :Tabularize /&<CR>` or in insert mode with `:imap <Leader>at <ESC>:Tabularize /&<CR>i`. I choose `<Leader>` (which is the backslash by default) to avoid interference with the scrolling (`<CTRL>-e`). `at` simply stands for “align table”, but you are free to pick another mnemonic.

Comment: Sorry I have a lot of trouble in installing tabularize.vim as a plugin. I use Mac and Windows and Linux, I want to install tabuliarze.vim on all three, the supposedly autoloaded plugin directory just doesn't get autoloaded, I tried a whole bunch different directories but it just doesn't get loaded, is there a way to "force load" tabularize.vim, say put in vimrc file . "loadplugin /.vim/plugin/after/tabularize.vim"

Comment: On Unices the following should be enough: 1) git clone git://github.com/godlygeek/tabular.git 2) cp -r -u tabular/* ~/.vim

Comment: Sorry, the <ESC>,<Leader> stuff is literally type in or use the control-V trick.

Comment: @ZwingliTannenbaum What about trying either of then and check which one works? A try will not nuke your system.

Comment: You could also use the Align plugin.

Comment: you could also include the line delimiters to the pattern: `:Tab /&\|\\\\ ` will do the trick.

Answer (score 24):

In emacs, AUCTeX includes `align.el`, which provides the command `align-current`: select the content of the table, and run `M-x align-current`, and it will auto-align the columns, producing the same result as in @Marco's answer

Comment: Sorry I don't use EMACS, how to do it in VI or ultraedit?

Comment: @ZwingliTannenbaum, I don't use VI or ultraedit :)  Marco's presented one approach in vim, and your question just asked if there was some editor that did table-editing well.  If vi or ultraedit are actually requirements in your question, you may want to edit it to clarify that a bit.

Answer (score 7):

On a mac

**With Texshop**

1) You can use  a matrix panel

[image]

2) Remark from Alan Munn

In TeXShop you can also use a spreadsheet for the cells and then paste them with Paste Spreadsheet Cells from the Macros menu

**With TextMate**

[image]

1) you begin with a selection like this

```
  12 15 13
  1 2 3
```

then you select "convert selection to table" or you type "shift control command T"  to get

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
12 15 13\\
\hline
1 2 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

2) you can use "Create Table" and you give the number of rows and column then with TAB you can move from cell to cell

Comment: In TeXShop you can also use a spreadsheet for the cells and then paste them with Paste Spreadsheet Cells from the Macros menu.

Comment: @AlanMunn Now I no longer use TexShop  also I had forgotten this possibility. I add your remark in my answer

Comment: How to do this in WinEDT?

Comment: I don't know WinEdt sorry :(

Answer (score 6):

**Disclaimer:** I also use the `Tabular` plugin in `Vim` (see Marco's answer). `:)`

There's a similar `Vim` plugin called [`Align`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) which behaves pretty much the same as `Tabular`.

```
moon & 456456456423423534 & 2342523
sun & 234324 & 3453
```

By issuing `:Align &`:

```
moon & 456456456423423534 &  2342523
sun  &             234324 &     3453
```

You can also use multiple separators at once, e.g, `:Align = + - \* /`.

There's also another command called `AlignCtrl` which has more options, including text alignment (left, right, center). By using the `>` operator, you can right-justify the table just like the question example.

Lots of examples can be found in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pix/vim-align).

Answer (score 4):

When I studied Astronomy over 20 years ago knowledge of Unix was assumed.

```
$ more myfilename.csv
moon & 456456456423423534 & 2342523
sun  &234324 &        3453
```

and now

```
$ cat myfilename.csv | column  -t                     
moon  &  456456456423423534  &  2342523
sun   &  234324              &  3453
```

With little fiddling you can easily align columns to the right!

Answer (score 4):

The next function uses the tabular plugin in Vim to automatically align table columns as you type them (once you have typed the first row):

```
function! s:ealign()
    let p = '^.*&\s.*$'
    if exists(':Tabularize') && getline('.') =~# '^.*&' && (getline(line('.')-1) =~# p || getline(line('.')+1) =~# p)
        let column = strlen(substitute(getline('.')[0:col('.')],'[^&]','','g'))
        let position = strlen(matchstr(getline('.')[0:col('.')],'.*&\s*\zs.*'))
        Tabularize/&/l1
        normal! 0
        call search(repeat('[^&]*&',column).'\s\{-\}'.repeat('.',position),'ce',line('.'))
    endif
endfunction
```

To make it work only with tex files add the following to your `vimrc` file:

```
augroup ft_tex
    au!
    au Filetype tex inoremap <buffer> <silent> & &<Esc>:call <SID>ealign()<CR>a
augroup END
```

Answer (score 4):

For winedt, there is a plugin: [TeXtab](http://winedt.org/Plugins/TeXtab.php). You can find the installtion instructions in the page itself. To quote from there:

The macro formats selected lines with respect to `&` and `\\`. It disregards `\&`

There are two ways to format the selected lines:

formatting with blanks leading and trailing `&` and `\\`:

```
aaaaaaaaaa&bb\&bbbbbb&ccccccc&&\\
eeee&fffff&gggg&hh&ii&jjjjjjj&kkkkkk\
```

will be changed to

```
aaaaaaaaaa & bb\&bbbbbb & ccccccc &    & \\
eeee       & fffff      & gggg    & hh & ii  & jjjjjjj & kkkkkkkk \
```

formatting without blanks between text and separators:

```
aaaaaaaaaa&bb\&bbbbbb&ccccccc&  &\\
eeee      &fffff     &gggg   &hh&ii &jjjjjjj&kkkkkk\
```

**How do you use the macro:**

Select full lines containing lines of a tabular block. Choose in menu `Edit` one of the menu item `Format TeX-Tables with blanks` or `Format TeX-Tables without blanks` (ALT e x or ALT e o).

Comment: This one also answers the question [Kile vs WinEDT vs TexShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46647/27635). See my answer there.

Answer (score 3):

**OpenOffice.org** allows to use any character as column separator for **CSV** (comma-separated values file format), so if you write large tables, you can put their data in a separate file and edit it there.

[Here is some how-to on this functionality.](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#Logic-fam)

Answer (score 3):

**1. LaTable and Tablas**

On Windoz, you can use LaTable

[LaTable at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latable)

or Tablas

[Tablas 3.0](http://www.informatica.us.es/~calvo/latex_en.html)

LaTable may have some small quirks under Win7. Both programs produce LaTex code to copy and paste into a LaTex manuscript, or saved as separate files, which you can `input` in your manuscript.

**2. CSVed and uniCSVed**

[Sam Francke](http://home.hccnet.nl/s.j.francke/software/software.htm) has written two very potent programs for manipulating CSV-files. You can easily adopted those to a LaTex workflow. Have a look at [the home page of CSVed and uniCSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/index.html)

[CSVed](http://home.hccnet.nl/s.j.francke/csved/csvedsetup.exe) is the most feature rich of the two programs. You can manipulate CSV-files in more of less every thinkable ways. CSVed is especially capable for editing CSV-files with lot of records, which you can `input`as table body in a `longtable` or `tabular` environment. The author is also looking into the possibility to add options to save to LaTex format (also an option to automatically escape LaTex special characters). *Limitation*: You cannot save in a UTF8 format (uniCSVedit can). Until the export filter is ready, you have to `input` the file between suitable table environments in your manuscript, after you have added `\\`. On the other hand, you can use [Nicola Talbot](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/index.html)'s [datatool](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/datatool)-package to merge the resulting CSV-file into a LaTex table.

uniCSVed has less features than CSVed, but you can save your file in Unicode (also without BOM). Links to uniCSVed are:

[uniCSVed with installer](http://home.hccnet.nl/s.j.francke/csved/unicsvedsetup.exe)
[uniCSVed portable](http://home.hccnet.nl/s.j.francke/csved/uniCSVed.zip)

uniCSVed can save the CSV-files in a format usable for LaTex (*i.e*. with `&` and `\\`).

1. Open a file to convert (has to be UTF8 with or without BOM), or create a new file
2. Go to TAB Modify 2 and add the suffix `\\` to the last column
3. Go to first TAB and change separator at Other `&`
4. Open menu File - Encode in  and select UTF-8 wo BOM
5. Save your file and is ready for LaTeX

**TeXmaker**

Also, the free cross-platform LaTeX editor 
[TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index) has a very capable *Table Wizard*. But as most Wizards, this is a one-shot. When you have closed the Wizard, you are left with the usual LaTeX-code in the manuscript. It cannot be *reloaded* in the Wizard for further editing.

Comment: How to do this in WinEDT?

Comment: @Zwingli Tannenbaum. The author of Tablas has some WinEDT macros on his homepage. http://www.informatica.us.es/~calvo/prog/macros.zip

Comment: latable and tablas work with linux/wine! small but excellent for the job.