# Kile vs WinEDT vs TexShop

Tags: kile, texshop, winedt

Question 1.
When I type `\begin{document}`
What keyboard shortcut can I use to so TexShop/Kile/WinEDT will automatically type the following: `\end{document}`

Question 2. How to do the following in WinEDT/Kile, I alrealdy know texshop

```
Before:
moon&456456456423423534&2342523
sun&234324&3453

After:
moon & 456456456423423534 & 2342523
sun  & 234324             & 3453
```

Answer (score 5):

In WinEdt:

1. Type `}` after `\begin{document}`, that is: type

   ```
   \begin{document}}
   ```

   You can also use `>` after `\begin{something}` to change the environment name to something else. For example, typing `>` after `begin{tabbing}` in the following example

   ```
   \begin{tabbing}
   ....
   \end{tabbing}
   ```

   prompts you for inserting a new environment name. If you insert `tabular` you get

   ```
   \begin{tabular}
   ....
   \end{tabular}
   ```

   Moreover, the string `\end{{` triggers environment completion. It searches for the last opened environment and closes it.
2. See Harish Kumar's answer to your question [Which text editor to make tables scripts human readable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117844/27635)

Answer (score 2):

In TeXShop, if you turn on Command Completion, TeXShop will automatically complete environments.  For example, type:

```
\begin{document}
```

<kbd>ESC</kbd>

and

```
\end{document}
```

will appear. <kbd>ESC</kbd> is the standard key for command completion.

In the preferences you can change this to <kbd>TAB</kbd> if you prefer.

Additionally, <kbd>Control-⌘-C</kbd> will close the current environment. (Also available from the Source menu).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the autocompletion feature in Kile, you will get `\end{document}` automatically. What I mean by that, is that when you start typing a command, you'll get a list of possible completions. Choose the appropriate one, and hit enter.

[image]

If you do not have this autocompletion feature, you can turn it on in the settings (Settings --> Configure Kile), under Kile --> Complete:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can go to Settings --> Configure Kile, look under LaTeX --> Environments in the left panel, and check the box for "Automatically complete \begin{env} with \end{env}". Write `\begin{environment}` and hit enter -- `\end{environment}` will be added.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to Torbjørn T.'s answer, if have autocomplete enabled in Kile but for some reason you you need to close an environment manually, you can do it with the combination Ctrl+Alt+E,C (i.e. first the three keys, then the one).