# What is your favorite vi or vim command trick?

Tags: vim

I just saw a similar question about Emacs/AUCTeX so this one was coming. I use nvi for all my editing including TeX and it would not change it for anything. However, even after almost 20 years of use I never stop to be amazed by clever trick people show me of and on.

This is my favorite list of nvi tricks (to be edited and improved over next couple of days):

**1)** Do not forget to use key mappings! Don't forget also that the whole power of Unix is on your fingertips as there is nothing easier than to invoke shell commands in nvi.  Combination of this two ideas is very potent.

**a)** Even though nvi has no built in spell checker it doesn't mean that we can't do a spell checking. Actually it is even easier than in most "user friendly editors". This is the most useful line in my **.exrc** for TeX editing.

```
map v :w^M:!ispell %^M:e!^M^M
```

The spell checking is done by pressing ESC+v. Note that people who prefer aspell over ispell can put something like

```
map v :w^M:!aspell check  %^M:e!^M^M
```

**b)** Another useful keyboard mapping specifically for TeX users.

```
map ^X :w^M:!make pdf clean %^M^M
```

What is does it enables you to tex your most recent edit by pressing **Ctrl+X** which pending on your pdf-viewer is automatically updated. Almost  WYSIWYG for nvi users. Ok for people who want to add this into their **.exrc** files note that tex-ing is actually done with **make** utility. So I do have my own home cooked Makefile in my working directory. Targets pdf and clean are described in the Makefile.

**2)** nvi comes with pretty sensible sets of default values. However a carefully crafted **.exrc** can dramatically increase productivity of editing. This is my complete **.exrc**.

```
set autoindent
set autoprint
set cedit=^[
set extended
set file=^[
set number
set ruler
set shiftwidth=4
set showmatch
set showmode
set tabstop=8
set verbose
set wrapmargin=8

map V !}fmt -w 72 ^M
map v :w^M:!ispell %^M:e!^M^M
map ^X :w^M:!make pdf clean-ps %^M^M
```

Probably two of the most underappreciated options which were not present in the original **vi** editor are `extended` option which allows you to use extended regular expressions (think `egrep`) and  `cedit=^[` (`^[` which is ESC in the verbose mode) allows you to use command history in **ex** mode.

There are two other options which I do not have in my **.exrc** file but I find it very useful. By default nvi search is case sensitive. We can override this behavior by setting option `ignorecase` (`ic`). Since I tend to use extended regular expressions this is not essential feature for me. Second non default option which is very useful is incremental search. Just set `searchincr`
and you will see what nvi matches words as you type in each letter of your search string.

**3)** Using abbreviations coming soon.

**4)** Buffers, markers and similar coming soon

**5)** Batch editing for beginners coming soon.

**Edit:**

This edit is inspired by  Stefan Kottwitz comment. My favorite thread on vi/vim from stackexchange is ["What is your most productive shortcut with VIM?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1218429). I almost fall of the chair after reading the first answer "Your problem with Vim is that you don't grok vi".

Comment: See [What are your favorite Vim tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95072/what-are-your-favorite-vim-tricks) on SO, with currently 142 answers.

Comment: +1 for using nvi! :-D (and the spell checker tip) too bad vim doesn’t have all the repetition goodness of the originals.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<sup>**Disclaimer:** I usually edit `.tex` files in Vim, but I don't use the [`Vim-LaTeX`](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) suite.</sup>

I wouldn't say the following suggestions are tricks *per se* - they are provided by third-party plugins - but they actually help me with my usual TeX workflow:

## [`snipMate`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) [image]

*Created by Michael Sanders*

> **From the manual:** `snipMate.vim` aims to be an unobtrusive, concise `vim` script that implements some of TextMate's snippets features in Vim. A snippet is a piece of often-typed text that you can insert into your document using a trigger word followed by a `<tab>`.

`snipMate` helps me a lot, mainly because it offers snippets for several languages out of the box, including TeX. For example, when editing a file `mydoc.tex`, typing

```
begin<tab>
```

will expand to an environment block of the form

```
\begin{env}

\end{env}
```

with the cursor selecting the word `env`. After typing the environment name, hitting `<tab>` again will take the cursor to

```
\begin{env}
   |        
\end{env}
```

for me to type. The snippets list for TeX is not that big, but the plugin seems to have a fairly easy syntax for us to create custom snippets. Here's the code used to create the above snippet:

```
# \begin{}...\end{}
snippet begin
\begin{${1:env}}
    ${2}
\end{$1}
```

So far, so good.

## [`Tabular`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3464) [image]

*Created by Matt Wozniski*

> **From the manual:** Sometimes, it's useful to line up text. Naturally, it's nicer to have the computer do this for you, since aligning things by hand quickly becomes unpleasant. While there are other plugins for aligning text, the ones I've tried are either impossibly difficult to understand and use, or too simplistic to handle complicated tasks. This plugin aims to make the easy things easy and the hard things possible, without providing an unnecessarily obtuse interface. It's still a work in progress, and criticisms are welcome.

`Tabular` helps me a lot when I'm trying to add elements in a `tabular` environment. It organizes the columns in a human-readable format. Let's suppose we have the following <s>mess</s> entries:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    Hello world & I love ducks & Vim rocks\\
    Think of a very long entry & How was your day & Quack!
\end{tabular}
```

It's quite confusing, but `Tabular` can help us. I usually enter in `Visual` mode, select the two rows and then issue

```
:'<,'>Tabularize /&
```

and we are done. The new rows now look like

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    Hello world                & I love ducks     & Vim rocks\\
    Think of a very long entry & How was your day & Quack!
\end{tabular}
```

I can also apply `:Tabularize /&`, but I prefer to delimit my scope. A similar plugin `Align` can also be used for this purpose, see my answer to [Which text editor to make tables scripts human readable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46362/which-text-editor-to-make-tables-scripts-human-readable/46568#46568).

## [`surround`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) [image]

*Created by Tim Pope*

> **From the manual:** `Surround.vim` is all about "surroundings": parentheses, brackets, quotes, XML tags, and more. The plugin provides mappings to easily delete, change and add such surroundings in pairs.

I usually use this plugin when editing source code from other languages. Let's suppose I have the following text enclosed between double quotes:

```
"Hello world"
```

By calling `cs"'`, the double quotes are automatically replaced by single quotes. I decided to make a different use of `surround`, so I took an example from the documentation and adapted to my TeX needs. First of all, I have the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType tex let b:surround_45 = "``\r''"
```

Note that `45` is the ASCII code of `-`. Now I can simply call `cs"-` and my text

```
"Hello world"
```

becomes

```
``Hello world''
```

The documentation has a few examples on TeX snippets.

---

For those who want to try the plugins I listed above, I highly recommend the use of the awesome [`pathogen`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) [image] plugin created by Tim Pope.

> **From the manual:** Manage your `runtimepath` with ease. In practical terms, `pathogen.vim` makes it super easy to install plugins and runtime files in their own private directories.

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: I started using vim-operator-surround rather than surround, so I could add custom brackets such as $\langle\rangle$ with `cs(<`. I didn't know normal surround could do customization. Do you think it could work in my case as well? Also, can you now do things like `da"` to remove the double quoted sentence?

Answer (score 7):

I use the `vim-latex` suite, and absolutely love it. However, I've found the following tweaks quite useful to help me compile my documents.

(These commands will be most useful to Linux users)

1. I like to 'toggle' between seeing the compiler output and not. With the setup below, I simply press <kbd>t</kbd> which toggles between 'silent' and 'verbose' mode
2. I like to be able to choose which compile method I use- either `latex`, `pdflatex`, etc. I can use

   - <kbd>f</kbd> just to `latex` the main file
   - <kbd>F</kbd> to use `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` the main file
   - <kbd>P</kbd> to use `pdflatex` on the main file
   - <kbd>F6</kbd> to view the main `pdf` file (calling `evince`)
   - <kbd>F4</kbd> to view the main `dvi` file (calling `xdvi`)
3. Choosing the main file with the `vim-latex` suite requires creation of a separate file in the current working directory. The script below `grep`s the current file and searches for `%*** mainfilename.tex`; if it doesn't find any, then the current file is the main file, if it does find one, then the matched expression is the main file

## ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim

```vim
" by default make the compile verbose
let g:Myvar="noisy"

" function to compile the mainfile, either verbosely or not
function! CompileMainfile()
    if g:Myvar=="noisy"
    :! MakepdfMainfile.sh %
   else
    "echo "quiet"
    :! MakepdfMainfile.sh % noshow
   endif
endfunction

" latex => dvips => ps2pdf
function! DvipsMainfile()
    if g:Myvar=="noisy"
    :! compileMainfile.sh -d %
   else
    "echo "quiet"
    :! compileMainfile.sh -dq %
   endif
endfunction

" pdflatex
function! PdflatexMainfile()
    if g:Myvar=="noisy"
    :! compileMainfile.sh -p %
   else
    "echo "quiet"
    :! compileMainfile.sh -pq %
   endif
endfunction

" just latex
function! Justlatex()
    if g:Myvar=="noisy"
    :! compileMainfile.sh %
   else
    "echo "quiet"
    :! compileMainfile.sh -q %
   endif
endfunction

" function to toggle between Noisy and Quiet
function! ToggleNQ()
    if g:Myvar=="noisy"
     let g:Myvar="quiet"
     echo "Silent mode ON"
    else
     let g:Myvar="noisy"
     echo "Silent mode OFF"
    endif
endfunction

:map f :w<CR>:call Justlatex()<CR>
:map F :w<CR>:call DvipsMainfile()<CR>
:map P :w<CR>:call PdflatexMainfile()<CR>
:map <F4> :! viewMainDVI.sh %<CR>
:map <F6> :! viewMainPDF.sh %<CR>
:map t :call ToggleNQ() <CR>
```

## /usr/local/bin/compileMainfile.sh

```bash
#! /bin/bash
#
# compileMainfile.sh
#
#   December 2011
#
#   Purpose: compile a .tex file either using latex, pdflatex, or
#               latex=> dvips=> ps2pdf, in silent mode or verbose mode
#   examples
#           compileMainfile myfile.tex          # just latex myfile
#           compileMainfile -d myfile.tex       # latex => dvips => ps2pdf
#           compileMainfile -p myfile.tex       # pdflatex myfile
#
#           add the -q flag for SILENT (or quiet) mode
#           compileMainfile -q myfile.tex
#           compileMainfile -qd myfile.tex
#           compileMainfile -qp myfile.tex
#
# See pgs 249 & 250 of BASH COOKBOOK for examples of getopts- really useful!


# argument check
ERROR="Too few arguments : no file name specified"
[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && echo $ERROR && exit  # no args? ... print error and exit

# define functions
function makepdf ()
{
    echo "======================================="
    echo "Main file is $mainFile.tex"
    echo "======================================="
    if [ $quiet -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "VERBOSE mode on"
        # latex mainFile.tex
        [[ $uselatex -eq 1 ]] && [[ $convertdvips -ne 1 ]] && latex $mainFile
        # latex => dvips => ps2pdf mainFile.tex
        [[ $convertdvips -eq 1 ]] && makepdf.sh $mainFile 1 && echo "DVIPS"
        # pdflatex
        [[ $usepdflatex -eq 1 ]] && pdflatex $mainFile && echo "PDFLATEX"
        egrep 'undefined' $mainFile.log
        egrep 'multiply-defined' $mainFile.log
        egrep '\\end occurred when \\iftrue' $mainFile.log
    else
        echo "SILENT mode on"
        if [ $convertdvips -eq 1 ]
        then
            # latex => dvips => ps2pdf mainFile.tex
            echo "DVIPS"
            nohup makepdf.sh $mainFile 1 &
        elif [ $uselatex -eq 1  ]
        then
            # latex mainFile.tex
            echo "just LaTeX"
            nohup latex $mainFile &
        elif [ $usepdflatex -eq 1 ]
        then
            # pdflatex
            echo "PDFlatex"
            nohup pdflatex $mainFile &
        fi
    fi
}


# set default values of flags
quiet=0
uselatex=1
usepdflatex=0
convertdvips=0

# check flags, and change defaults appropriately
while getopts 'abpqd' OPTION
do
 case $OPTION in 
  q)    quiet=1
   echo "Silent mode ON"
   ;;
  p)    usepdflatex=1
        uselatex=0
   ;;
  d)    convertdvips=1
   ;;
  ?)    printf "Usage: %s: [-a] [-b value] args\n" $(basename $0) >&2
        exit 2
        ;;
 esac 
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

# check we haven't called with -dp 
# which would mean dvips and pdflatex
[[ $usepdflatex -eq 1 ]] && [[ $convertdvips -eq 1 ]] && echo "Option clash: cannot be called with -dp" && exit

# name of MAINFILE
mainFile=$1

# incase we're compiling from within the CHAPTER file
set `grep -F %*** $1 | tr -d "%*" `""
dummy=$1

# delete the file extension
mainFile=${mainFile/%.tex/}
dummy=${dummy/\.*/}

# check the length of the dummy string, if it's 0 then latex the current file
# otherwise latex the referenced latex file
if [ $dummy ]
then
 mainFile=$dummy
fi

# call the makepdf function
makepdf
exit
```

## /usr/local/bin/MakepdfMainfile.sh

```bash
#! /bin/bash
#
# December 2011
#
# Purpose:  compile latex->dvips->ps2pdf
#       either silently or verbosely
#
# Options:  noshow
#
# examples: MakepdfMainfile.sh myfile.tex noshow    # silent mode
#       MakepdfMainfile.sh myfile.tex       # verbose mode

# argument check
ERROR="Too few arguments : no file name specified"
[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && echo $ERROR && exit  # no args? ... print error and exit

# assume VERBOSE mode by default
noshow=0
[[ $# -eq 2 ]] && [[ $2 == "noshow" ]] && noshow=1  # otherwise turn on SILENT mode

# name of MAINFILE
mainFile=$1

# incase we're compiling from within the CHAPTER file
set `grep -F %*** $1 | tr -d "%*" `""
dummy=$1

# delete the file extension
mainFile=${mainFile/%.tex/}
dummy=${dummy/\.*/}

# check the length of the dummy string, if it's 0 then latex the current file
# otherwise latex the referenced latex file
if [ $dummy ]
then
 mainFile=$dummy
fi

echo "======================================="
echo "Making PDF : Main file is $mainFile"
echo "======================================="
if [ $noshow -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "SILENT mode on"
    nohup makepdf.sh $mainFile 1 &
else
    echo "VERBOSE mode on"
    makepdf.sh $mainFile 1
    echo "======================================="
    echo "Made PDF : Main file is $mainFile".tex
    echo "======================================="
    egrep 'undefined' $mainFile.log
    egrep 'multiply-defined' $mainFile.log
    egrep '\\end occurred when \\iftrue' $mainFile.log
fi
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, Chris! I'm updating my Vim configuration. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

### Tables

I write a lot of tables which are all pretty much the same. I bind most of my commands to `;word` , table being bound to `;tab`. It asks for number of columns, caption, and whether or not it's fixed width. I of course use the Tabularize plugin as well for formatting.

```
function! TableCreator()
        let curline=getline('.')
        call inputsave()
        let cols = input('Enter number of columns: ')
        let caption = input('Caption: ')
        let centering = input('Fixed width? (y/n) :')
        call inputrestore()
        exe "normal a\\begin{table}[!h]\r\\caption{" . caption . "\\label{tab:}}\r\\begin{center}\r\\begin{tabular}{\e"
        let numcols = cols
        while cols > 0
                if centering == 'y'
                        exe "normal ap{4cm}\e"
                else
                        exe "normal ac\e"
                endif
                let cols = cols-1
        endwhile
        exe "normal a}\e"
        let cols = numcols - 1
        exe "normal a\r\r\r\e"
        exe "normal a\\end{tabular}\r\\end{center}\r\\end{table}\\ \\\\"
endfunction
```

### Spell Checking

I write a couple different languages, and depending on my target audience. I use this to conveniently switch between them.

```
" Spell Check
let b:myLang=0
let g:myLangList=["nospell","de","en_gb","en_us"]
function! ToggleSpell()
  let b:myLang=b:myLang+1
  if b:myLang>=len(g:myLangList) | let b:myLang=0 | endif
  if b:myLang==0
    setlocal nospell
  else
    execute "setlocal spell spelllang=".get(g:myLangList, b:myLang)
  endif
  echo "spell checking language:" g:myLangList[b:myLang]
endfunction
```

Comment: Cool tricks! `:)`

Comment: @EricR: How do you use the script?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, the two scripts I have shown here I have bound as follows: `imap ;tab <ESC>:call TableCreator()<cr>` and `nmap    <silent><F7>    :call ToggleSpell()<CR>`

Answer (score 3):

Keeping it down to the plugins the most relevant for LaTeX editing.

## [NERD Commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter)

*By Martin Greenfell, aka scrooloose*

Quick commenting of blocks of text, automatically using correct comment notation for the detected language (including TeX).

It is either used in single line mode, where

- <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will comment the current line
- <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> will uncomment the current line
- <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> will toggle the comment status of the current line.

<kbd>\</kbd> is the default "[leader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1764263/445621)" key; you might have it configured differently (I personally use <kbd>Space</kbd>). The command can of course be mapped to whatever one wants, but these are the default mappings.

I also often (perhaps *more* often) use it in visual multiline mode by moving to the first line, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for visual line selection, moving to the last and then commenting the whole block with the above mappings.

There are more functions and commands available; see the documentation in the above link.

## [Gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/)

*By [Steve Losh](http://stevelosh.com/)*

"Graphical undo". Modern Vim versions actually keep undo *trees* in memory that are directly traversable by <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>. This can be a "life saver" to rescue file modifications even after accidentally issuing input after having walked backwards in the undo history, but walking the tree is mostly a blind trial and error process using these commands.

Gundo opens a split where it draws the actual undo tree and lets you traverse it graphically. It is not something that I use every day, but the times when I need to walk in the undo forest, it is massively useful, not least when writing LaTeX.

## [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim)

*By [gmarik](http://gmarik.info/about)*

[Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) used to be absolutely essential for handling plugins, and all Vim users should be thankful for it. Vundle is a noteworthy improvement of the concept, directly plugging into primarily Github and the official Vim script catalogue.

This might not seem like much, but it allows you to keep the full information on installed plugins within `~/.vimrc`, which makes it a lot easier to synchronize setups across machines and keep everything tidy in version control itself in a more straightforward way than can be done with Pathogen.

## [Better Rainbow Parentheses](https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim)

*By kien*

There are many versions of this type of plugin. It highlights matching parentheses in different colors per matching pair.

I do not have it activated by default, but have a mapping to toggle it on and off in case I feel lost in the land of brackets and braces, which can certainly happen in LaTeX.

## [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box)

I have noticed that I am not alone in finding [Vim-LaTeX](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) (aka LaTeX-suite) too heavy and intrusive while editing. I actually had it enabled by default for years, but the only functions I used intentionally was the folding and perhaps the "smart quotes". On the other hand, several of its functions was a direct and recurring hindrance for my editing.

Some might like the Vim-LaTeX method, but for me LaTeX-Box lightweight and non-intrusive approach fits much better, and it is never in my way.

LaTeX-Box enables "smart completion" (context aware of bibliography entries, labels, environments, etc.), [Latexmk](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) integration (e.g. continuous compilation on file changes), folding, and more. See [the documentation](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box/blob/master/doc/latex-box.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the mention of LaTeX-Box; I've also found that Vim-LaTeX  can be a hindrance to me at times!

Comment: Afaik vim already saves all your changes as a tree, but it is a bit tricky to traverse it. Does this mean I don't need to install Gundo before I actually really need it?

Comment: @ThomasAhle: Yes, as mentioned above Vim saves undo trees by default, that you can traverse with `g+` and `g-`, though it is quite flaky to do it blindly like that, since the trees easily become complex with several branches. Gundo helps with the visualization. Once installed, it lies latent until you activate it, which opens up a pane with the graphical undo-tree, so it does not hurt just to have it installed. I suppose you could try to install it "live" upon demand, but it seems like something you would not want to do if you are in the situation that you really need it.