# PDFLatex Halt on Warning/Typesetting Error

Tags: warnings

I'm using vim to write my latex and have a makefile that simply runs PDFLatex on the main TeX file. The output from this is often incredibly dense and difficult to parse with the human eye. What's more there is usually a great deal and useful information will have left the terminal window before I have seen it.

I am quite used to situations like in gcc where you can force it to halt on warnings, which would currently be my desired behaviour (but I can't find a way to do this). What's more, there are things that I would like to be warned about (for example overfull bounding boxes) that don't come with "LaTeX Warning" along side them. So I would be unsure of how to grep this to get all useful information.

Is there any standard command line method to achieve what I am looking for? Alternatively, a method of parsing the log file to easily list these typesetting errors would be useful.

Comment: have you seen the answers to [what-is-your-favorite-vi-or-vim-command-trick](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52750/what-is-your-favorite-vi-or-vim-command-trick)

Comment: I've just read them and I don't see how any apply. The best I can find is a toggle between "verbose" and "silent" output mode, which isn't what I'm asking for.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the script `texloganalyser` that's installed along with TeX Live. For example `texloganalyser -h file.log` will show "Overfull `\hbox`" warnings.

Comment: Also there's `pplatex` `ppdflatex`, which can be obtained from http://www.stefant.org/web/projects/software/pplatex.html  This program runs `latex` or `pdflatex` and nicely summarizes the errors and warnings.

Comment: I think `\usepackage[l2tabu, abort]{nag}` will get you at least part of the way there.

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to make TeX stop at warnings.

You can go to Plan B: the script `texloganalyser` (included in TeX Live) has facilities for showing different bits of the log file.

As pointed to by John Collins, also `pplatex` and `ppdflatex` are meant to do this: https://github.com/stefanhepp/pplatex

Comment: I think a redefinition of \PackageWarning to internally call \PackageError should be a feasible way to stop at some warnings (which then become errors, of course). If there are other warning macros, they could probably also be altered. It's not completely clear, what the benefit of that approach were, but it's at least possible.

Comment: @PatrickHäcker I don't think that making errors out of warnings really solves the problem, as the compilation is driven by a Makefile.