# Editing LaTeX tables in MS Excel

Tags: tables, excel

I have a big LaTeX table that I want modify it in Excel, is there any solution?

There is some good solutions for converting Excel table to Latex tables.

Comment: You can use CSV files and set up it to use `&` as the values separators.

Comment: [`excel2latex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex). I only know that it exist, never used it.

Comment: Have a look at [datatool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool). what kind of modification in excel that it cannot be done in latex itself?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/comprehensive-list-of-tools-that-simplify-the-generation-of-latex-tables

Comment: @Sigur Thanks. My table is not so simple, it contains merged cells and indeed I want change the merging style.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.Thanks. Reverse it! I need latex@excel. BTW I use it, it's save a lot of time for me.

Comment: @texenthusiast I want merge some cells vertically and move some rows and columns. These are possible in LaTeX but are not easy to do.

Answer (score 10):

You can import a latex table into excel.

1. In the excel main menu select File -> import ...
2. choose csv or text as file type
3. choose "&" as your delimiter (un-select all others)
4. finish

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know there exists no solution you want, even if you want to merge cells.

The only thing that exists is [excel2latex](http://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex), but I never saw a result of this Excel macro that has not to be reworked.

Perhaps a pretty printing of your table could help you. For example write all `&` below each other so you can see the columns of your table in your `tex` file.

For example:

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{:}l*{5}c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}    &       & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Node ID}                     \\ 
\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Date | Time} & 25             & 28             & 29             & 31              & 32              \\
\midrule
9/29/2007 00            &00     & \ding{108}     & \ding{108}     & \ding{108}     & \ding{108}      & \ding{108}      \\
9/29/2007 01            &00     & \ding{109}     & \ding{109}     & \ding{109}     & \ding{109}      & \ding{109}      \\
9/29/2007 23            &00     & \ding{108}     & \ding{108}     & \ding{109}     & \ding{108}      & \ding{109}      \\
\midrule
9/29/2007 23            &00     & \textbullet    & \textbullet    & \textbullet    & \textopenbullet & \textopenbullet \\
\midrule
9/29/2007 23            &00     & $\blacksquare$ & $\blacksquare$ & $\blacksquare$ & $\square$       & $\square$       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

In this was you can easy see the columns of your table and you can change the mergin style by inserting `\multicolumn`. The bad example would be something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{:}l*{5}c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Node ID} \\ \cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Date | Time} & 25 & 28 & 29 & 31 & 32 \\ \midrule
9/29/2007 00&00 & \ding{108} & \ding{108} & \ding{108} & \ding{108} & \ding{108} \\
9/29/2007 01&00 & \ding{109} & \ding{109} & \ding{109} & \ding{109} & \ding{109} \\
9/29/2007 23&00 & \ding{108} & \ding{108} & \ding{109} & \ding{108} & \ding{109} \\ \midrule
9/29/2007 23&00 & \textbullet & \textbullet & \textbullet & \textopenbullet & \textopenbullet \\ \midrule
9/29/2007 23&00 & $\blacksquare$ & $\blacksquare$ & $\blacksquare$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thank, Is there any tex editor that could prettify the code? IDEs could to that for most programming languages.What about LaTeX?

Comment: In Emacs (use AUCTeX for serious business) you can use `align-current` which works fairly well.

Comment: @PHPst for **vim** read the section “tabular” in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52762/14066).

Comment: `Gnumeric` is able to export table to LaTeX via `Save As` command.

Comment: @PHPst: For prettyfing latex code: https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx

Comment: excel2latex is actually very good. I have been using it with minimal post-processing.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script that does exactly that. It can be used with `multicolumns`, `multirows` and supports `booktabs` package. (in fact, I only implemented it for `booktabs`, but implementation for normal `hline` is just a matter of minutes.) It will create one worksheet for each table.

Usage: python tex2excel YOUR_INPUT_LATEX_FILE OUTPUT_EXCEL_NAME

I know this is a late answer, but hopefully it could help future people from google.
[click here for the code](https://gist.github.com/kun-zhou/ccf80dd5f42deca6c7a9f7c410f0ef17)