# App for making tables

Tags: tables

I know of a few web-based apps that allow you to make tables, but they're all a bit clunky. Does anybody know of an app you can download that allows you to draw/edit tables and easily copy-paste code into latex?

Or, are there any other recommendations for the best way to draw a table for latex?

Comment: For OpenOffice there is a plugin called [`calc2latex`](http://calc2latex.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yeap, @HenriMenke has a point.  Check more info here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24897/using-excel2latex-in-excel-2010 and  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106883/editing-latex-tables-in-ms-excel