# How to line up the "&" to make tables readable in code

Tags: tables, texshop, code

I'm using TeXShop and I was wondering if there is a way to line up the "&" in the code for tables in Latex, to make them readable and able to modify them without having to compile permanently.

For example, I have :

```
test&44&2
test2&24&3
```

and I want :

```
test   &   44  &  2
test2  &   24  &  3
```

I don't know if there is a solution to my problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you heard about the `tabular` environment?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie in latex and stackexchange ! Yes, I tried to use the tabular environment but I'm not sure how it works? I failed to install the plugin on my mac...

Comment: What do you mean by "plugin on my mac"? Have you installed [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/)?

Comment: Yes, I have installed MacTex. I have huge econometric tables but it is very difficult to track mistakes for example. That's why I want to line up the "&"

Comment: Does this help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46601/134144

Comment: Thank you, I was already on this topic but it does not help me. My tables are already in tex format and I am trying to align the "&" in the code to make them more readable without having to compile.

I don't know how to make this in TexShop so I tried to the Tabular plugin in Vim, but I fail...

Comment: Forgive the self publicity, but If you use Vim you might like [my table filter](https://github.com/thruston/perl-vim-table) that is tex-aware.

Comment: You can use the `tab` key...

Comment: Since vi was mentioned, I'll counter with `M-x align-current` in Emacs (not sure it it is `auctex` that provides the tex aware alignments here), really nice feature. Still wonder why other editors don't copy some of these features 

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what features texshop has for aligning table columns but if you save those rows it is easy to format them on the commandline and put them back. I think mac os has `column`

If you save

```
test&44&2
test2&24&3
```

as `file`

then

```
column -t -s\& -o' & ' file
```

produces

```
test  & 44 & 2
test2 & 24 & 3
```

here `-t` says to make tabular output, `-s\&` says to split up the input on `&` and `-o' & '` says to put `_&_` between each column after padding them with spaces.

Comment: on my mac ox 10.9.5, the `-o` option is not recognized. Whatever I try to escape the `&`  as `-s` argument it disappears in output, only whitespace is used.

Comment: @jfbu what shell do you use? singe quotes around space & space work for me in bash, still you could use something else like zzz and fix it up later in the editor

Comment: I am using bash. Yes, quotes like you use should be fine. The problem is that my version of column (man page date July 29, 2004) simply refuses `-o` option `column: illegal option -- o`, `usage: column [-tx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]` and has no substitute.

Comment: @jfbu  $ column -?
column: unknown option -- ?

Usage:
 column [options] [<file>...]

Options:
 -c, --columns <width>    width of output in number of characters
 -t, --table              create a table
 -s, --separator <string> possible table delimiters
 -o, --output-separator <string>
                          columns separator for table output; default is two spaces
 -x, --fillrows           fill rows before columns

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see column(1).

Comment: my version does not even have `-h` and does not accept long form options such as `--table`.

Comment: @jfbu I should have stuck to sed :-)

Comment: as long as you don't use perl :-)